# Definite descriptions and 'concrete numbers' in language

Tags: semantics, noun-phrases, denotation

'Concrete numbers' are a type of phrase consisting of a number and a unit expressed with a noun, such as 'two metres', 'three apples' etc. Historically called *numerus numeratus*

Take '5 men', it does not definitely describe any group of men in existence, however it does indentify correctly the exact amount/particular measure type, a *unique idea*, Hence it may or may not denote a particular group of men depending on the context.

'5 men entered a bar, and played a game of darts'

This is therefore an indefinite description and follows the rules that it can *describe* something and denote it contextually.

However in some context it is treated as a phrase that unambiguously denotes the idea of *amount* of a certain type.

'The price is 5 dollars'

If '5 men' denoted the *idea* of that amount of men then it would be difficult to explain what an idea is doing entering a bar.

Why is it that these kind of phrases which seemingly is an indefinte description and *describes* (contextually it may denote the object being described) is seen as unambiguously denoting the abstract idea of the amount?

Using an indexical phrase like 'The Price' in 'The Price is 5 dollars' with something ('5 dollars') that is not a proper noun (or some other unambiguous denoting phrase) seems ungrammatical.

Comment: In English, five men or five meters is the number of men or meters, respectively, not the amount. Five pounds of coffee, that is an amount. Doesn't five meters or five kilos exist in your language? :)

Comment: why is 'five pounds of coffee' both an indefinite descriptor and a referring phrase for a particular amount?

Comment: An amount of an uncountable noun and a number of a countable one.

Comment: Indefinite descriptor? five and green are pretty definite.

Comment: 5 meters can be width, height or length. five apples is not shiny apples. So you confusing me by saying: but 'five apples' can describe something but *we strangely use this structure of phrase to refer to these concepts*,  I have no idea what you mean.

Comment: @Lambie Sorry, for example if I say 'I am one person' it is a description, yet I might say '100 people is a big quantity' in which case I am 'referring' the the 'quantity' as an idea. If we say '1 person is a small number of people', I am not a small number of people, I am a living person, yet I am '1 person'.

Comment: Please follow this: I am sure this works the same way in your language. The distinction you are making does not work: One person versus one hundred people. And "one hundred people is a large number". Not a big quantity. These figures are adjectives describing nouns. It is just not that difficult. [number] followed by a noun.

Comment: @Lambie the examples weren't idea but the point I was making we use these concrete numbers as descriptions of things, and then also discuss them as entities in themselves using adjectives such as 'large' or 'small'.

Comment: First of all, concrete number is somewhat meaningless. large numbers, small numbers, large amounts, small amounts. I still do not understand what you are trying to say.

Comment: It seems to me that in *the price is five dollars* the reason that *five dollars* cannot refer to an entity in the real world has more to do with *the price is* than with *dollars*. Compare *I put five dollars on the counter*; *I had walked five meters from the front door when I realized I had forgotten my hat*. It is not clear to me what your question is. The first question in your last paragraph is ungrammatical.

Comment: And to be sure, you can get the non-denoting type (like *the price is…*) with *men*, too: *a human pyramid requires at least six men*; *a poorly prepared attack would cost at least two hundred men*.

Comment: @Keelan this is my point when discussing 'price' or 'amount' we use these phrases as if they denote specifically some idea. Even 'it will cost 5 dollars' is no issue to me, as it is *describing* the value of item(s) that I would need to exchange.

Comment: What’s the actual question here?

Comment: Any indefinite noun phrase can denote a class of things or a particular thing depending on context.   "An elephant never forgets."   "An elephant escaped from the zoo."

Comment: Use "the" and you can have definite NP's with quantifiers in them.   "The five men came back alive."

Answer (score 1):

> '5 men entered a bar, and played a game of darts'

> 'The price is 5 dollars'

You are pointing out that in the first, “5” may describe a real-world state of affairs - some men who really are walking into a bar.

In the second, you note that “5” is an amount, but it does not “determine” the noun “dollars” in the sense of implying they exist somewhere - if all dollars in the world vanished, the price of something could still be 5 dollars.

I think the number is not the factor causing this distinction. My guess is semantically, however the mind comprehends a number of something, it can happen independently of other aspects of meaning, such as, is it determined or undetermined? Is it in the physical world or an idea?

Those conditions can occur without numbers, and I don’t think numbers change them -

*Men walked into a bar.*

This could be interpreted as “some men” in certain contexts.

*Dollars were found on the street.*

It sounds like it had to happen in the real world.

*The price of the goods is in men.*

You have to pay in men, for the good. I think it is a “general noun”, it does refer to a concept, but it does not state that that object is currently existing (in some context, like, the world).

I think you are interested in the difference between abstract and concrete nouns but you think the number is what is responsible for conveying if something is abstract or concrete. But other noun attributes can be used in both cases too, like adjectives. I think the first is concrete more because of the verb “walked”, implying something sort of tangible or factual is occurring, even if it were a fantasy world, like “5 dollars walked into a bar.” The second is abstract more because of the context of “The price is…”. A price will always be abstract because it conveys a sort of condition to be met. You can state a condition and it does not presuppose that the condition can be met. So it doesn’t entail that any specific dollars exist in a specific place. It also is not important which dollars. It just (would) require something of that category. This is similar to any statement about an entire category: “Men are beautiful” - even if this is in an alternative world in which someone is inventing a concept for a fictional story, “men”, and announcing their characteristics.

My answer is not that deeply developed but I think you are interested in abstract vs. concrete nouns and you think the number is controlling that whereas I think they can actually be separated from each other.

Comment: The concrete/abstract distinction is definitely a part of it, I just don't understand how you can say 'the price is x' where x isn't an explicit reference like 'that chair over there', it seems like an identity statement where an indexical phrase is being pointed to an object but '5 dollars', '5 men', due to the determiner '5' are both really descriptive phrases.

Comment: Like if I were to say 'the issue is men' it is obvious that it means 'all men', however there exists no set of 'dollars' to be the price, what they mean is a sort of abstract concept that it needs to be dollars and there needs to be five of them.

Comment: If I were to guess, we do this with 'abstract' 'nouns for ease, as financiers, scientists ect prefer to use a number and unit or a number and currency.

Comment: It's no harder to say "the price is $5" than it is to say "the chair is green". Clearly the chair is real, but it is not the color _green_; this is a different construction. _Be_ is the auxiliary for a lot of kinds of predicate constructions.